# calling method with IOException

Tags: java, methods, ioexception

I had this program with which i have to check if the value the user entered is present in the text file i created in the source file. However it throws me an error everytime i try to call the method with IOException. Please help me out thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class chargeAccountModi
{
    public boolean sequentialSearch ( double chargeNumber ) throws IOException
    {

        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);

        int index = 0;
        int element = -1;
        boolean found = false;

        System.out.println(" Enter the Charge Account Number : " );
        chargeNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

        int[] tests = new int[18];
        int i = 0;
        File file = new File ("Names.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        while(inputFile.hasNext() && i < tests.length )
        {
            tests [i] = inputFile.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
        inputFile.close();

        for ( index = 0 ; index < tests.length ; index ++ )
        {
            if ( tests[index] == chargeNumber )
            {
                found = true;
                element = index;

            }

        }
        return found;
    }

    public static void main(String[]Args)
    {
        double chargeNumber = 0;
        chargeAccountModi object1 = new chargeAccountModi();

        try 
        {
            object1.sequentialSearch(chargeNumber);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) 
        {

        }



        System.out.println(" The search result is : " + object1.sequentialSearch (chargeNumber));

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact error message? Don't just swallow the exception! Add `ioe.printStackTrace()` to the `catch` block so you can see what happened.

Comment: check ``Names.txt`` file path. You should specify absolute path here.

Comment: Rafik991 ...  the file contains only test. like

Comment: it contains only tests like
1111
2222.. now when i try to run it.. it says exception all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking on your method sequentialSearch there is everythink ok. But try to change main:
But remember that in your Names.txt file you should have only numbers because you use `scanner.nextInt();`, so there should be only numbers or method will throw exeption InputMismatchException.

Check also path to Names.txt file you should have it on classpath because you use relative path in code `File file = new File ("Names.txt");` Names.txt should be in the same folder.

```
public static void main(String[]Args)
{
    double chargeNumber = 0;
    chargeAccountModi object1 = new chargeAccountModi();

    try
    {
        System.out.println(" The search result is : " + object1.sequentialSearch(chargeNumber));
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception!!!");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: it contains only text like
1111
2222 now after using the main method u had sent me.. it says exception all the time. is my way of calling the text file right??

Comment: You have to put your Names.txt file in the same folder that you have your java project.

Answer (score 0):

Few tips and suggestions:

First of all: Don't forget to close the Scanner objects! (you left one unclosed)

Second of all: Your main method is highly inefficient, you are using two loops, in the first one you read and store variables, in the second one you check for a match, you can do both at the same time (I've written an alternative method for you)

Third little thing: The variable "element" is not used at all in your code, I've removed it in the answer.

And last but not least: The file "Names.txt" needs to be located (since you've only specificied it's name) in the root folder of your project, since you mention an IOException, I figure that's what's wrong with the app. If your project is called Accounts, then it's a folder called Accounts with it's source and whatever else is part of your project, make sure the file "Accounts/Names.txt" exists! and that it is in the desired format.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ChargeAccountModi {

    public boolean sequentialSearch(double chargeNumber) throws IOException {
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
        int index = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        System.out.print("Enter the Charge Account Number: " );
        chargeNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
        int[] tests = new int[18];
        int i = 0;
        File file = new File ("Names.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        while(inputFile.hasNext() && i < tests.length ) {
            tests [i] = inputFile.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
        inputFile.close();

        for (index = 0 ; index < tests.length ; index ++ ) {
            if (tests[index] == chargeNumber) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        keyboard.close();
        return found;
    }

    public boolean sequentialSearchAlternative(double chargeNumber) throws IOException {
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean found = false;
        System.out.print("Enter the Charge Account Number: " );
        chargeNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
        int tests = 18;
        int i = 0;
        File file = new File ("Names.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        while(inputFile.hasNext() && i<tests) {
            if (inputFile.nextInt() == chargeNumber) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        inputFile.close();
        keyboard.close();
        return found;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double chargeNumber = 0;
        ChargeAccountModi object1 = new ChargeAccountModi();
        try {
            System.out.println("The search result is : " + object1.sequentialSearch(chargeNumber));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Handle the exceptions here
            //The most likely exceptions are:
            //java.io.FileNotFoundException: Names.txt - Cannot find the file
            //java.util.InputMismatchException - If you type something other than a number
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```